# Show image from the article in blog layout

Tags: content, images, category-blog

I'm looking for some help with our website. So, we have this news site which gets lots and lots of new articles in short period of time and therefore it requires lots of journalists working on it.

The workflow would be much easier if we wouldn't have to set Intro Image or Full Text Image each time on each article to be shown in the blog layout next to the article.

Some 3rd party modules know how to pick any image from the content of the article. Since the website is online and 3rd party modules wouldn't be the best solution for us, I'm wondering is there any way to tell Joomla to pick any image from the article instead of just Intro Image or Full Text Image?

I've been working around php a bit but couldn't find any line that would help me.

Thanks,
Jan

Comment: From what part of the article is the image you're trying to pull? is it from the intro text or the full text; Is the first occurrence or second or etc.? And, where are you trying to show the image? Is it 'category blog' pages?

Comment: The image is from full text, the first one that would appear in the article. I would like to show it in the category blog.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following in the overridden article layout file (e.g. `templates/[your-template]/html/com_content/article/default.php`):

- Search for images using a regular expression
- Use the first image found as a display image for your article (you can use a default image if no images are found)

For the regular expression used to find images, you can check [this post](http://www.itoctopus.com/no-wrong-thumbnail-image-when-sharing-k2-articles-through-facebook) where we searched for images in a K2 article (essentially used for Open Graph tags). The regular expression line should be exactly the same in your code.

Comment: Seems like this might help. Problem is, I'm not much of a programmer. I guess this is the part of the code you're reffering to?
`<?php if (isset($images->image_fulltext) && !empty($images->image_fulltext)) : ?>
 <?php $imgfloat = (empty($images->float_fulltext)) ? $params->get('float_fulltext') : $images->float_fulltext; ?>
 <div class="pull-<?php echo htmlspecialchars($imgfloat); ?> item-image"> <img
 <?php if ($images->image_fulltext_caption):`
(Part 1)

Comment: `echo 'class="caption"' . ' title="' . htmlspecialchars($images->image_fulltext_caption) . '"';
 endif; ?>
 src="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($images->image_fulltext); ?>" alt="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($images->image_fulltext_alt); ?>" itemprop="image"/> </div>
 <?php endif; ?>`
(Part 2)

Comment: Could you help me out a bit more, please?